# JavaScript Coin Flip "You Win/lose" Message Not Working

Tags: javascript

I have this coin toss function , so far it correctly displays "Heads" or
 "Tails" randomly. However, I want a message to appear saying "You win" whenever the coin lands on heads. But right now it only displays 
"You loose" regardless of which side the coin landed on. How can I fix this?

```html
<DOCUTYPE html>

  <head>
    <title>Coin Toss V1</title>
    <style>

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button id="click" type="button">CLICK ME</button>
    <p>
      <b> You got:</b> <span id="result"></span>
    </p>
    <script>
      document.getElementById('click').onclick = click;

      var heads = 0;
      var tails = 0;

      function click() {
        x = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0);
        if (x) {
          flip("heads");
        } else {
          flip("tails");
        }
      };

      function flip(coin) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = coin;
      };

      if (x == "heads") {
        document.write("you win!");
      } else {
        document.write("you loose");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</DOCUTYPE>
```

Comment: Change the condition to `x == "heads"` also I guess you need to put your if-else part inside `flip()` function

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: Can we please teach new people to use `===` as much as possible? This is a prime example of a question where one should tell people to use `===` and not come with this coercing `==` confusion.

Comment: Check the x = heads, that works in VB.NET or VB, but not in JS, you must use the == or ===.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your sample code -- this answer will help resolve the most pressing problem.

I would suggest re-structure your `click` function as follows:

```
function click() {
    x = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0);
    if (x) {
      flip("heads");
      document.write("you win!");
    } else {
      flip("tails");
      document.write("you loose");
    }
};
```

And remove the following block of code:

```
  if (x = heads) {
    document.write("you win!");
  } else {
    document.write("you loose");
  }
```

A few things worth pointing out:

1. `heads` is different than `"heads"`. The former represents a specific string variable while the latter is a string value.
2. `=` differs from `==`. The former assigns a value to a variable while the latter makes a equality comparison.
3. Inside `click`, you are assigning `x` a value of `true` or `false`, so your `if` statement below should have compared `x` to true or false.
4. In your original code, your bottom `if` statement fires immediately when the page is loaded -- before the `click` function is executed. It would make sense to move your `document.write` code inside your `click` function so that it can output the result of the coin flip `click` function.

I'd also suggest reading up about global variables (e.g., your variable `x`) and why they are problematic.

Comment: Please vote to close typo questions as they are unlikely to help anyone in the future.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan For the OP, this isn't a typo. It reflects a misunderstanding of some basic concepts. Instead of closing the question, I'd rather help the OP understand the issues in his/her code.

Comment: Then it's a duplicate of many other questions, like [If variable equals the number 1](//stackoverflow.com/q/18110478).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The OPs question is slightly different and the issues in OPs code are slightly different, but you could certainly make the case that it's an approximate duplicate. Closing it as a duplicate would still serve to assist the OP rather than closing it as a typo which would help no one.

Comment: @Elitezen I've updated my answer to be a bit more helpful. There was another issue with your code that I didn't notice at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix a bug here. You are assigning the value of heads to x, rather than doing a comparison.

```
if (x = heads){
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful : you are assigning in your condition, not comparing!
Put

```
if (x == heads)
```

instead of

```
if (x = heads)
```

Otherwise you are assigning heads to x and then doing if(x) which always evaluates as false as long as heads = 0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two equals signs for the equality comparison operator, try:

```
if (x == heads)...
```

Other than that one line, you're not using the heads or tails variables.  You can remove them and use

```
if (x)...
```

In your second if statement, just like you did in the first.

Answer (score -1):

The result check, should be inside the funciton flip(), so it's executed each time the coin is flipped.

```
function flip(coin) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = coin;

    if (x = heads){
        document.write("you win!");
    } 
    else {
        document.write("you loose");
    }
};
```